# How to use empty props?

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component

**Hello**,
how can i use these empty props (attributes) in VUE component?

**I have this HTML**:
app-page is component name

```
<app-page table>one item</app-page> 
<app-page flex>two item</app-page>
<app-page table>test item</app-page>
```

**One VUE component**

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: "AppPage",
    template: `
      <div :is="table" class="table">
        <slot></slot>
      </div>
      <div :is="flex" class="flex">
        <slot></slot>
      </div>
    `
  };
</script>
```

**I want render it like this**

```
<div class="table">one item</div>
<div class="flex">two item</div>
<div class="table">test item</div>
```

I haven't worked with VUE for a long time, so I forgot about this a bit.

Comment: Can you explain your requirement little more, just by reading what it's tough for me to understand it

Comment: I want the HTML to render as it is in that comment. If has oneItem attr so render it like in first comment and if has twoItem attr so render it like in second comment. I trying use props in vue component, but without value (empty) and render specific piece of code.

Comment: what does `oneItem` prop contain, is it just a boolean (true|false)? Can it be more then 1 or 2 items?

Comment: I updated my question, look. Sry im not so good in English, unfortunately

Comment: do you want to render that specific div based on what you pass into the AppPage component? Like if you pass table it renders that and so on?

Comment: Oh yes, practically yes. I want the component to render differently based on the attribute

Comment: check my example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a prop inside the component, value that you are gone pass in to the it. In this particular case I call it type, then you can add more types without adding more props.

```js
Vue.component('AppPage', {
  props: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  template: `
      <div :class="type"><slot /></div>
    `
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<app-page type="table">table</app-page>
<app-page type="flex">flex</app-page>
```

Comment: is this possible with empty attributes? Just table / flex without type prefix?

Comment: Sure, you can use the example palash has given you. IMO this is more flexible as you don't have to add more props and add to the v-if incase you choose to use more variants, like grid ect. "Just" add the class. Is there a reason for not wanting to have the `type="table"` @TheCzechTayen

Comment: Thanks, I've tweaked it a bit for my project, but the solution works. My memory is back.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass props to `AppPage` but just need to declare the type of the prop as `Boolean`. This will automatically set the passed prop to `true` and other props to false.

Then you can update your template to dynamically set the class and render based on passed prop value like:

```
<div v-if="table || flex" :class="{'table': table, 'flex': flex}">
  <slot></slot>
</div>
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
Vue.component('app-page', {
  props: {
    table: Boolean,
    flex: Boolean
  },
  template: `
    <div v-if="table || flex" :class="{'table': table, 'flex': flex}">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({el: "#myApp"})
```

```css
.table {padding: 4px 8px; border: 1px solid green; margin: 5px;border-radius: 4px;}
.flex {padding: 4px 8px; border: 1px solid orange; margin: 5px;border-radius: 4px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="myApp">
  <app-page table>one item</app-page>
  <app-page flex>two item</app-page>
  <app-page table>test item</app-page>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tweaked it a bit for my project, but the solution works. My memory is back.